# how to represent tree structure in C# pulling from database and then display on web page

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I am working on project where I need get genealogy of a product. For example consider there is product A which produced B1 and B2, where B1 again produced C1, C2, C3 and B2 proudced C4,C5,C6. Now if user either inputs either B1 or C2 or any product it should return entire family.

Currently in database I have below table structure

-entryproudct exitproduct
-A B1
-A B2
-B1 C1
-B1                C2
-B1                C3
-B2                C4
-B2                C5
-B2                C6

and  in C# have a class for product whose instances is used to represent A,B1,B2.....etc i.e to represent products.....

1. Now how do I construct its family tree or genealogy in C# when one product is given?
2. Do I need to change table structure or is it enough to construct tree?
3. How hard is it to display visually tree structure on web page either using asp.net mvc or ajax

I will be using asp.net mvc,linq, sql server 2008.

Answer (score 0):

Displaying a tree shouldn't be too hard.  Here's someone using recursion to do it:
http://weblogs.asp.net/raduenuca/archive/2011/04/24/asp-net-mvc-displaying-a-tree-view-using-a-recursive-declarative-helper-and-jquery.aspx

Here's one in JQuery:
http://weblogs.asp.net/mikebosch/archive/2008/11/25/hierarchical-treeview-with-asp-net-mvc-jquery.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show a treeview like Windows Explorer you can use:
http://www.dotnetperls.com/treeview

If this is a binary tree then u may think about building a tree with jQuery:
http://frank-mich.com/jQuery/

Answer (score 0):

you can writte an store procedure using recursive query, and the data gotten store in list, where product object has like a member a List.